# Python-Selenium "element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium, automation, sudoku

I was trying to fill sudoku with selenium, but every time raise an *element not interactable*

Relevant code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://sudokutable.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_wrapper"]/main/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').send_keys('1')
```

I trying this too, but same result:

```
sleep(1)
num = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_wrapper"]/main/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')
num.click()
num.send_keys('1')
```

If someone know any method to send keys, Im very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to close the Cookie pop-up.

Then we need to find the empty cells and try to fill the cell. The empty cell can be recognized by the `class` attribute in the `svg` tag.

```
DOM when the cell is already filled
<div class="game-grid__cell" data-group="1" data-row="0" data-column="4">
    <svg class="default" viewBox="0 0 72 72">

DOM when the cell is empty
<div class="game-grid__cell" data-group="0" data-row="0" data-column="1">
    <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
```

```
# Imports required:
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://sudokutable.com/")
actions =ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Close Cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"agree_cookies"))).click()

# Find empty cells and use indexing to fill them up
cell = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='game-grid__group'][1]/div/*[name()='svg' and @class='']")
actions.move_to_element(cell[0]).click().send_keys("1").perform()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of `num.click()`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", num)
```

To send the keys use:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys('1')
```